# Does django support Teradata as a back end database?

Tags: python, django, database, teradata

I want to make a django powered intranet web app. Need to know that does django support Teradata as a back-end database? as there is some requirement where my web app has to make connection with Teradata to get and process data and send it back to Teradata database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Django does not support Terada backend by default. But you can use mxODBC Django Database Engine. Most of the Django ORM should work with it. Here is the link to get more information on how to do it on [eGenix website](http://www.egenix.com/products/django/)